# Issue in resizing PVC: Only dynamically provisioned pvc can be resized and the storageclass that provisions the pvc must support resize

Tags: mongodb, storage, cluster-computing, minikube, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to create pvc which can be resized later on demand.

I am using this code from github for [mongodb pvc](https://github.com/scriptcamp/kubernetes-mongodb).

I followed all the steps and pvc is created as below:

```
PS C:\Users> minikube kubectl -- get pvc
NAME         STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mongo-data   Bound     pvc-4a22efc0-9fd3-42dc-80a7-db86e8f2c189   1Gi        RWO            standard       32m
```

I edited the file mongodb-pvc.yaml and changed the storage field to 2 GB. storage: 2Gi and then again executed kubectl apply  command and got below error:

```
  PS C:\Users> minikube kubectl -- apply -f mongodb-pvc.yaml
    Error from server (Forbidden): error when applying patch:
    {"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"PersistentVolumeClaim\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"mongo-data\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"accessModes\":[\"ReadWriteOnce\"],\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"storage\":\"2Gi\"}}}}\n"}},"spec":{"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"2Gi"}}}}
    to:
    Resource: "/v1, Resource=persistentvolumeclaims", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=PersistentVolumeClaim"
    Name: "mongo-data", Namespace: "default"
    for: "mongodb-pvc.yaml": persistentvolumeclaims "mongo-data" is forbidden: only dynamically provisioned pvc can be resized and the storageclass that provisions the PVC must support resize
```

I tried using the storageclass also, but unable to map it correctly.

Please help, I am a beginner in Kubernetes and especially in PVC.

Answer (score 12):

In order to resize a PVC, it is required to have the attribute `allowVolumeExpansion` set to “true” in your storage class definition. Otherwise, you won't be able to perform the update.

You can follow these steps and add this attribute to its YAML:

1. In Kubernetes Engine -> Storage -> Storage Classes, select the storage class that you are using for your PVC.
2. Go to its YAML file and add the instruction. As is explained in the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-expansion#using_volume_expansion):

   ```
    allowVolumeExpansion: true
   ```

Once the YAML file is modified, try to perform the resize of the PVC once again

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script for it

This should work on minikube and k3s

- get the storage class name
- enable volume exapansion on it

  ```
  query='{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.storageclass\.kubernetes\.io/is-default-class=="true")].metadata.name}'
  default_sc=$(kubectl get sc -o=jsonpath="$query")

  echo patching storage class "[$default_sc]"

  kubectl patch storageclass $default_sc -p '{"allowVolumeExpansion": true}'
  ```